# Load an Image in EmguCV's Imagebox, damned IImage

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have managed to load an Image on the control only by right-click' selecting the "load image" option while in runtime.

I want to know if there's a way to load it passing specifically the Image object,
since when I try doing as I normally would, setting it like `imagebox.Image = (...)`
would give an error because the `imagebox.Image` is a "IImage" object.

any tips? 
thanks :)

Comment: Show code and the exact exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Image<BGR, Byte> rstImg = new Image<BGR, Byte>(imageBox.Image.Bitmap);
imageBox.Image = rstImg;
```